# <<EOF specify a variable

Tags: bash

I use a command in bash such as:

```
gmx_d energy -f ener.edr -o outfile.xvg <<EOF
1
2
3
4
5
EOF
```

to print in file outfile.xvg 5 different properties. Is there any way to add a variable such as

```
gmx_d energy -f ener.edr -o outfile.xvg <<EOF
    $i 
    EOF
```

and ideally I would like to reproduce the same output with the 5 different properties in the same output file

Comment: Why not just do a loop?

Comment: You  can always include variables in here-documents, and the way is exactly as you have shown. It is just not necessary here.

Comment: For your second sample, you'll need to use "<<-". `man bash`: `If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're trying to provide input (on stdin) to the gmx_d program, pipe it:

```
printf '%d\n' {1..5} | gmx_d energy -f ener.edr -o outfile.xvg
```

or

```
seq 5 | gmx_d energy -f ener.edr -o outfile.xvg
```